# How to replace values of non-empty cells in a Google Sheets Column with a "String"?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to replace prices with "Email" in all the sheets. As column D is same for all sheets I tried this code.

```js
function doTest() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    sheet.getRange('D1:D').setValue('Email');
    //if (sheet.getRange('D1:D').getValue() != ""){
    //  sheet.getRange('D1:D').setValue('Email');
    //}
  }
}
```

.setvalue('Email') simply replaces all the cell values in that column.

What condition should I  use to iterate and change only the prices in that column.

Before :

[image: Sheet Screenshot]

After Running this Script: [image]

Comment: I am not sure, but you can first check if value contains $ sign or value is numeric.

Comment: I thought the same but dont know how to do that. Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

Your script isn't checking the cells at all.

---

#### Solution:

First you need to get the values in your range, this can be achieved by using `getValues()`. This pushes all of the values in that range to an array, which we can use for the next step.

```
var values = sheet.getRange('D1:D').getValues();
```

Then go through each of the array objects using a `for` loop and an `if` statement to check if the value is a number or not using `typeof`. If a numeric value is found, we can use `setValue()` using `j + 1`(as arrays are 0-indexed, we need to add 1) for the row in `getRange()` :

```
for (j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
  if (typeof values[j][0] === 'number') {
    sheet.getRange(j + 1, 4).setValue('Email');
  }
}
```

---

#### Example 1 (slower):

```
function replaceBlanks() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    var values = sheet.getRange('D1:D').getValues();
    for (j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
      if (typeof values[j][0] === 'number') {
        sheet.getRange(j + 1, 4).setValue('Email');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

#### Example 2 (faster):

As @TheMaster correctly pointed out, the script will run faster if we build an array and use `setValues()` instead, so here's the code to do that if you're experiencing performance issues:

```
function replaceBlanks() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    var values = sheet.getRange('D1:D').getValues();
    var array = [];
    for (j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
      if (typeof values[j][0] === 'number') {
        array.push(['Email']);
      } else {
        array.push([values[j][0]]);
      }
    }
    sheet.getRange(1, 4, array.length).setValues(array);
  }
}
```

---

#### References:

- [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [JavaScript `if` Statements](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp)
- [JavaScript Arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)
- [`typeof`](https://www.mkyong.com/javascript/check-if-variable-is-a-number-in-javascript/)

Comment: It'll be faster if you also created a output array and used `setValues()` instead.

Comment: @TheMaster great spot! I've added this in as well as the code already provided.

Comment: Great!!````!````

Comment: Flawless!! Thanks @ross

Answer (score 0):

Your range `'D1:D'` is an array of arrays, to make your `if` condition work in the intended way, you need to access the value of each single cell of the range separately:

```
var range=sheet.getRange(1,4,sheet.getLastRow(),1);
for(var i=1; i<=sheet.getLastRow; i++){
      var cell=range.getCell(i,1);
      if (cell.getValue() != ""){
          cell.setValue('Email');
       }
    }
```

Comment: The script keeps on running forever but no change is taking place :(

Comment: This is because your range includes the whole D column - not sure how many rows it contains. A more elegant solution would define your range as getRange(1,4,sheet.getLastRow(),1) : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns

Comment: Thanks. But idk this is still taking an infinite time. Maybe @ross can answer.

Comment: @zig Read [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations)